# PHP - How to ignore numbers/numeric on string using explode() or preg_split() function

Tags: php, explode, preg-split

I want to make explode or preg_split function to ignore numbers/numeric.

```
$string = "my name is numbre 9000 900 1";

$dictionary = array("my", "name", "is", "number");

$words = explode(' ',$string);

foreach($words as $wrd):

if(in_Array($wrd, $dictionary)){
  echo $wrd;
}
elseif(in_Array($wrd, $dictionary) == FALSE){
  echo $wrd."->wrong";
}
```

the output I want should be:

```
my
name
is
numbre<-wrong
9000
900
1
```

not:

```
my
name
is
numbre<-wrong
9000<-wrong
900<-wrong
1<-wrong
```

any idea how do I do this?

Comment: Check if each word is in your dictionary _or_ [`is_numeric`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php).

Comment: what is the difference between you expected and actual `<-wrong`? your title doesn't really match the example you gave and that made your question a bit confusing.

Answer (score 2):

Your original method is just fine, we'd slightly modify that and apply the `preg_split`. Here, we check first for `is_numeric`, if `TRUE` we `continue`, then we `array_search` our dictionary, if `FALSE` we append `->wrong`, otherwise we `continue`.

#### Test

```
$str = "my name is numbre 9000 900 1 and some other undesired words";
$dictionary = array("my", "name", "is", "number");
$arr = preg_split('/\s/', $str);

foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    if (is_numeric($value)) {
        continue;
    } elseif (array_search($value, $dictionary) === false) {
        $arr[$key] = $value . "->wrong";
    } else {
        continue;
    }
}

var_dump($arr);
```

#### Output

```
array(12) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "my"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "name"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "is"
  [3]=>
  string(13) "numbre->wrong"
  [4]=>
  string(4) "9000"
  [5]=>
  string(3) "900"
  [6]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [7]=>
  string(10) "and->wrong"
  [8]=>
  string(11) "some->wrong"
  [9]=>
  string(12) "other->wrong"
  [10]=>
  string(16) "undesired->wrong"
  [11]=>
  string(12) "words->wrong"
}
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tcaveu/1/)

Comment: Hardcoding `if ($value === 'numbre')` seems to miss a main point of the code which is to check the words against the dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comment, you could use an or `||` to check if the string [is_numeric](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php).

Note that you might write your code a bit shorter:

```
$string = "my name is numbre 9000 900 1";
$dictionary = array("my", "name", "is", "number");
foreach(explode(' ',$string) as $wrd){
    if(in_array($wrd, $dictionary) || is_numeric($wrd)){
        echo $wrd . PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        echo $wrd."->wrong" . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Result:

```
my
name
is
numbre->wrong
9000
900
1
```

See a [php demo](https://3v4l.org/Big0q)